# Do sidekiq workers run if primary server not running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis

I have a rails app deployed to heroku (free version).

I have some mailers that I've set up to work via sidekiq.

I have a record, that might have a due date of September 5, 2020.

My worker is set up to send a mailer the day before. So on September 4, 2020, it should run the worker and send the mailer.

However, it appears to me that once the dyno stops running, these jobs will no longer run at the desired time. In other words, on September 4, 2020, the primary server isn't running, and therefore the redis server / sidekiq do not appear to work.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm wanting to queue jobs that will occur at specified times, regardless of whether the primary server is running / app is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Sidekiq and Redis are run on different severs to your main Web server. You can run your sidekiq server without having the Web server running.
Redis is generally run in Heroku as an add on and won't be listed as a dyno.
Under resources in Heroku it should list all the dynos your app is using. You should see a Web server and a sidekiq dynos both listed.
To only run sidekiq, turn off the Web server dynos from the heroku console.
Remember, you still need a way to queue your sidekiq jobs though. Often they will be queued by user interactions on the Web. If you don't have the Web server running, you could look at using something like the Clockwork gem to trigger your jobs.

Comment: Thank you. I do understand all that. I am using the front end website to run the action which queues the sidekiq job. My issue is this, if I queue the job to run in 10 minutes, it works fine, but if I queue the job to run in 24 hours, the job does not run. I was wondering if it had something to do with heroku server no longer running

Comment: I'm pretty sure when you schedule a job directly with Sidekiq it stores it in Redis like normal. The docs here:
https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs
Say it checks for scheduled jobs approximately every 5 seconds so as long as your sidekiq process and redis are still running it should work. I'd check to see if Redis is being stopped when you stop the web server.